# How to verify AWS S3 bucket details is valid or not using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

In my application am having a form, in that user should enter their AWS S3 details. Before saving the details I have to check whether the account is correct or not. I am building this application using Node js,mongodb,Angular js.

**UPDATE**
aws s3 details are

```
{
       "aws": {
        "key": "",
        "secretkey": "",
        "region": "",
        "bucket_name": ""
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "their aws s3 details"? What exact details are you collecting?

Comment: Thank you for your response ..I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try making a s3 client using aws s3 sdk and then try calling method that your app needs to. For example if you need to create an object in the provided bucket, Then simply try making test object  and see if it works. You can pass stored credentials like in below links:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-json-file.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');

AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: '...', secretAccessKey: '...' });
//make sure you pass proper credentials
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
fs.readFile('test-file.txt', function (err, data) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  var base64data = new Buffer(data, 'binary');
  const params = {
    Bucket: '...bucket-name-here...',
    Key: 'test-object.txt',
    Body: base64data
  };
  s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    //check error or data to see if you have proper permissions.
  });
});
```

Also see these examples for putObject method:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property
https://gist.github.com/homam/8646090

Comment: Thank you ..I will check and let you know

Comment: where params represent                                                                         
  var  params = {
        "accessKeyId": "",
    "secretAccessKey": "",
    "region": ",
 'bucket': ''
       };  these details right??

Comment: I have added example for you in the links

Comment: Ok its working..If i didn't pass proper credential means what will happen??Because i have to get all the credential(accessKeyId,secretaccesskey,region and bucket name) from user

Comment: you can try by passing incorrect credential and see it throws error. 
if(err) {console.log(err)}

Answer (score 3):

Using the AWS Javascript SDK you should make a headBucket request using the supplied credentials in the constructor.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ credentials, region });

s3.headBucket({
  Bucket: "examplebucket"
}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
})
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headBucket-property

If the request is successful you have access.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried this,but am getting The bucket policy does not exist error

Comment: No worries, I think most cases I've used policies but fine if you're not, you also have the headBucket which does a quick check to see if you have access.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the user credentials then you can use `aws-sdk` which is available as node module.

set the credentials in sdk config and use `S3` API to verify the given buckets.

> npm install aws-sdk

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
AWS.config.accessKeyId = "accessKey";
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = "secretKey";
AWS.config.region = "region";

var s3 = new AWS.S3();
```

You can refer the [site](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) for better understanding